# ''postcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, tailwind-css, postcss, postcss-cli

Even though I have postcss installed I still get the above error in the terminal when I try to build. I'm using this in conjunction with tailwindcss and my postcss.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require('cssnano'),
    ]
}
```

I've already updated all my packages and cleared the NPM cache. This isn't happening with any of my other builds. Could there be an error in my package.json file? Here is a portion of that:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^19.2.2",
    "dir-archiver": "^1.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "rtlcss": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "rtlcssConfig": {
    "options": {
      "autoRename": false,
      "autoRenameStrict": false,
      "blacklist": {},
      "clean": true,
      "greedy": false,
      "processUrls": false,
      "stringMap": []
    },
    "plugins": [],
    "map": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "postcss css/styles.css -o build/styles.css",
    "watch": "node-sass sass/ -o ./ --source-map true --output-style expanded --indent-type tab --indent-width 1 -w",
    "compile:css": "node-sass sass/ -o ./ && stylelint '*.css' --fix || true && stylelint '*.css' --fix",
    "compile:rtl": "rtlcss style.css style-rtl.css",
    "lint:scss": "wp-scripts lint-style 'sass/**/*.scss'",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js 'js/*.js'",
    "bundle": "dir-archiver --src . --dest ../_s.zip --exclude .DS_Store .stylelintrc.json .eslintrc .git .gitattributes .github .gitignore README.md composer.json composer.lock node_modules vendor package-lock.json package.json .travis.yml phpcs.xml.dist sass style.css.map yarn.lock"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "gsap": "^3.11.4",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.6.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "swiper": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm installs `dependencies` and `devDependencies` into node_modules, which is *very rarely* in your PATH. Node ships with a helpful command `npx` which can do this for you with `npx postcss`. Scripts in package.json run with node_modules/.bin in their PATH, so I'd also check that you're running `npm run build` and not just the postcss command. Otherwise, just install it globally.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I run `npx postcss` I get the following error: npm ERR! could not determine executable to run.
Also I am using `npm run build`

Comment: Installing postcss globally did the trick

Comment: @CiaranGaffey If this answer helped, could you please hit the checkmark on the left so it's easier to find for others in the future? If you fixed your own problem, feel free to add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Answer marked as correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using node v16.20.0 && npm -v 8.19.4

```
npm install -g postcss-cli
```

> Global installation resolved the issue.